# How do I change HTML table cell color on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, cell

I'm trying to change the background color of an HTML table cell when the user clicks on the cell. Any ideas on how to do this? I have access to the JS Prototype library, so any suggestions for Prototype or straight Javascript would be welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Ugly, but demonstrates the effect:

```
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';">Sample</td>
        <td onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Blue';">Data</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not well versed in the Prototype framework, but here's some raw Javascript that'll do what you're looking for:

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
if(table) table.onclick = function(e) {
    var target = (e || window.event).target;
    if (target.tagName in {TD:1, TH:1})
        target.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: #F00');
};​
```

**Test it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EX6R9/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over all the children of the table and add an click event to them

with prototype the code is:

```
$('your_table').observe('click', function(event) {
  var clickedCell = event.findElement('td');
  if (clickedCell) {
   clickedCell.setStyle({ background: '#dfd' });
  }
});
```