# Changing td color when clicking hyperlink inside the td

Tags: javascript, html, css, wicket

I am using Wicket to create a table that has multiple links and different functionality for each link. Now, I'd like to change the color of the td when the link is clicked. I have tried different code and end up either with just the part of the link changing or the td changing when clicked but then the link is'nt clicked.

```
<td width=30 onclick="javascript:this.style.background = '#009999';" style='width: 22.5pt;  background: #FF0004; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 30.0pt' id=redcell>
    <p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align: center'>
        <span style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>
            <a href="#" wicket:id="agent_one" value="1" >
                <b>
                    <span style='display:block; font-size: 12.0pt; color: white' >1</span>
                </b>
            </a>
            <o:p></o:p>
        </span>
    </p>
</td>
```

Comment: and I'd like to change the color of the other not clicked links to gray when any link is clicked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change HTML table cell color on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722465/how-do-i-change-html-table-cell-color-on-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "drill-up" the DOM hierarchy using the parentNode property. In your case, the TD is the grand-grand-parent element of the link (with a paragraph and a span in between) so what you need to add to your link would be something like this:

```
onclick="javascript:this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = '#009999';"
```

Or in the context of your full code:

```
<td width=30 style='width: 22.5pt;  background: #FF0004; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 30.0pt' id=redcell>
<p class=MsoNormal align=center style='text-align: center'>
<span style='font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: "Arial", "serif"; color: #222222'>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = '#009999';" wicket:id="agent_one" value="1" ><b><span                                                                          style='display:block; font-size: 12.0pt; color: white' >1</span> </b></a>
<o:p></o:p> </span>
</p>
</td>
```

Comment: I tried that already. But now I see that it might be the way I setup my tables.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<tr>
    <td onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Red';">Sample</td>
    <td onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'Blue';">Data</td>
</tr>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/enp2kvLk/)

Comment: I have tried that. I am starting to feel that the problem is based on the way I created my table. I wish I could show you guys a snapshot of how it looks. I tried my code on Notepad++ and running it on my browser it works, but moment I move it to wicket, my tables remain the same.