# Color table cells onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a 5x5 table, with each cell containing a word. When I click on the word, I want the color of the cell to be updated to a pre-defined color. In the example below, a table is set up with the colors encoded - what I want is them to be white until their corresponding word is clicked.

```
<TABLE BORDER="4" CELLSPACING="4" CELLPADDING="4">
    <TR>
        <TD BGCOLOR="#ffff00">Yellow</TD>
        <TD BGCOLOR="#00ff00">Green</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD BGCOLOR="#ff00ff">Purple</TD>
        <TD BGCOLOR="00ffff">Blue</TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722465/how-do-i-change-html-table-cell-color-on-click) is what you are looking for.

Comment: "Do my homework for me" What did you try?

Comment: That's a bit harsh @epascarello. I've not web-coded in anything more than basic HTML before, and it's certainly not for homework.

Comment: @James  no it is not. Person got answer for free without effort to try to figure something out.  It is very basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery you could do this:

```js
$('table td').on('click', function() {
  $(this).attr("bgcolor", $(this).attr("data-color"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<TABLE BORDER=4 CELLSPACING=4 CELLPADDING=4>
<TR>
<TD data-color="#ffff00">Yellow
<TD data-color="#00ff00">Green
</TR>
<TR>
<TD data-color="#ff00ff">Purple
<TD data-color="00ffff">Blue
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

For a larger project I'd recommend selecting the table by ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use vanilla Javascript you can add a simple `onClick` event listener and set the color. The color would need to be stored in a `data-bgcolor` attribute.

```js
const tableCells = document.querySelectorAll('TD')

tableCells.forEach( function (cell) {
  cell.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = e.target.dataset.bgcolor;
  })
})
```

```html
<TABLE BORDER=4 CELLSPACING=4 CELLPADDING=4>
  <TR>
    <TD data-bgcolor="#ffff00">Yellow</TD>
      <TD data-bgcolor="#00ff00">Green</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR>
    <TD data-bgcolor="#ff00ff">Purple</TD>
      <TD data-bgcolor="#00ffff">Blue</TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: this doesn't work in firefox: `tableCells.forEach is not a function`.